# Geography column not generated from SP in EF 5

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, entity-framework-5, sqlgeography

I'm having an issue with Entity Framework 5 and a stored procedure in my SQL database. I have a stored procedure that returns two VARCHARs, two INTs, and a GEOGRAPHY. When I generate the EF model from the DB only the first four columns are generated in the model while the geography is for some reason left out. I tried manually inserting the geography column return in the model but that didn't work. The closest thing I've found after some research is [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28592085/geography-column-returned-in-stored-procedure-not-shown-in-entity-framework-auto) that sadly went unanswered. All of the other instances of geography interacting with my application work fine it's just this one stored procedure.

My question is, what am I missing? Is there some obscure setting I'm missing when creating the stored procedure in the database? Or am I missing something when I generate the model in Visual Studio? Or some other quirk I haven't even considered?